# or Statement in database query to filter records in PHP MVC CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am writing the following code in PHP MVC CI to filter records.

```
$query = $this->_ci->db->get_where(
                       "tbluser", 
                        array("username" => $userName, "password" => md5($password))
                                  );
```

So, in the above statement it's like

```
Select * from tbluser Where username = 'somevalue' and password = 'somevalue'
```

How can I write the code if my database query is below.

```
Select * from tbluser Where username = 'somevalue' or password = 'somevalue'
```

Comment: Don't hash your passwords with md5... That's what http://php.net/password_hash is for.

Comment: @Mike: Many thanks for the code review. I will definitely take care of it.

Comment: I'm also trying to wrap my head around why you would ever want to execute the second query. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Use `$this->db->or_where();` function.

Comment: @LoremIpsum: Your comment is actually an answer. I have voted to reopen this answer. So you can place your answer and I can mark it.